# Grid layout (ul) of divs with different sizes

Tags: html, css, grid, html-lists

What would be the best way of achieving an unordered list that would look like this?

[image]

Comment: Are you open to js solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). As far as I know, it's probably the most popular tool used to achieve such layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've recently checked out Masonry, and it's really quite awesome. However, if I'm correct, Masonry works by have a defined column width. But with the example I posted, there are quite a few different width sizes. But if you know of any way of achieving this with Masonry, please share.

Comment: @JackArrgon Well, the layout is fixed? I mean does it always look the same as the image you showed?

Comment: Yeah, it would look the same.

Comment: @JackArrgon Okay, two choices here: lots of CSS, or using a `<table>`. If you use a `table`, then semantically it sucks, although it's easier. What do you prefer?

Comment: I think I've actually found the solution using Masonry. On the site it says, "The width of item elements can span multiple columns. Set columnWidth to match the width of a column in your grid layout." So I'm going to give that a go. http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-multi-column.html

Comment: @JackArrgon Oh -- cool. I expect the column width would be the minimum size of any of the "square" `li` in your case.

Comment: Yes, with Masonry and Isotope you need to chose the smallest common divisor for the column width. However, if the viewer's browser window is not very large and your tile size is wide, you will sometimes have gaps unless you do some clever sorting.