# How do i move my DIV up? And make them so they wont move when the window gets resized

Tags: html, css

The green textbox on the jsfiddle wont move upwards to the yellow one.. how do i fix this? And how do i make the boxes "unsizable", so they wont start going everywhere when the window gets resizded.
I think it has to do with the middle div, because when i type more in it, the side boxes goes down. 
I tried: `top: -20px;`, and `position: alternative / realative;` But they just dissapear

**I can´t add the link to the jsfiddle.. it should be in the comments.**

```css
         .container {
                max-width: 770px;
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 15px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .left, .right, .middle {
                float: left;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                position: initial;

            }
            .right {
                margin-right: 0px;
                float:right;
                position: initial;
            }

            .left-header, .right-header, .middle-header {
                background: #58C5B3;
                font-size: 10px;
                padding: 15px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                position: initial;

            }
            .middle{
                width: 500px;
                position: initial;
            }

            .left-text, .right-text, .middle-text {
                background: #FFFFFF;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 15px;
                position: initial;

            }
            ul {
             list-style-type: none;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             overflow: hidden;
             background-color:#55A7DB;
             color:black;
             line-height:22px;
             margin-left:auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             text-align:center;
             vertical-align:middle;
             border-radius: .2em;
             width: 780px;
             height: 42px;
                border-right: .2em;
            }

   li {
    float: left;
   }
   li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 010px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
   }
   li a:hover {
    background-color: #58c5b3;
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;}
   
   a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   }
   a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
   }
   a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   }
   .design{
    padding: 3px;
        padding-top: 3px;
       padding-right: 3px;
       padding-bottom: 3px;
       padding-left: 3px;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
       border-radius: 5px;
       position: relative;
            }
            .pluss{color:#7dc3b7;}
            .minus{color:#c5618b;}
            .space{height:20px;}
```

```html
  
    <body>
            <div class="container">

           <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
HOME</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
NEWS</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
ADMINS</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
LOGIN</a></li></ul>
           <br>
    



     <!-- LEFT  -->
        <div class="left" style="width: 25%">
                <div class="left-header">
                    updates<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                </div>
                <div class="left-text">
                    <!-- -->
                    <div class="minus"></div>
                    <div class="pluss">+ Added:<br>+ Added:<br><div class="minus">- Removed:<br>- Removed</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /// left-->
        <!-- MIDDLE -->
            <div class="middle" style="width: 47%">
                <div class="middle-header" style="background-color: #ce5b5b">
                   Welcome to (servername)!<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                </div>
                <div class="middle-text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat.<p>
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. 
                    </p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /// middle-->
            <!-- RIGHT -->
             <div class="right" style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="right-header" style="background-color: #e3c155 ">
                    login<i style="float:right;"  class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>


                </div>
                <div class="right-text">
                    <!-- -->You can have your own text in this box.
                </div>
            </div>

            <br><p>

        <!-- ///right-->
       




             <!-- left- secound row -->
             <div class="left" style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="left-header" style="background-color: #55A7DB">
                    INSERT TEXT<i style="float:right;"  class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>


                </div>
                <div class="left-text">
                    <!-- -->You can have your own text in this box.
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- ///left -seound row-->

            <!-- RIGHT - secound row -->
             <div class="right" style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="right-header" style="background-color: # ">
                    insert text<i style="float:right;"  class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>


                </div>
                <div class="right-text">
                    <!-- --> THIS TEXTBOX, (LIKE EVERYONE) WONT GO TO THE TOP, UNDER THE YELLOW ONE.
                </div>
            </div>

            <br><p>

        <!-- ///right - secound row-->
     





    </body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/etmLur9z/3/

Comment: Might this be a good solution for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351432/grid-layout-ul-of-divs-with-different-sizes

Answer (score 1):

Try to put all left divs inside one left container and the same for middle and right, when you do this, all boxes will show just below each other without spaces in between as in your fiddle.
And if you want to prevent them from resizing, you will have to give them a fixed width not percentages, or percentages with max-width:xxpx;

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. I want them to resize for the text, but not to get on a new line if the winow resizes,

Comment: I believe if you did put them in separate columns, this will solve your issues. did you try it?

Comment: I dont think im able to :p, not 100%in html or css, ca you try for me?